# How does memory allocation work in python in this case?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-management

Suppose I have a very large `numpy` array `a`, and I want to add the numerical value 1 to each element of the array. From what I have read so far:

```
a += 1
```

is a good way of doing it rather than:

```
a = a + 1
```

since in the second case a new array `a` is created in a different memory slot, while in the first case the old array is effectively replaced in the same memory slot.

Suppose I want to do the following instead:

```
a = 1-a
```

What would be the memory efficient way of doing the above?

Comment: `a` is an numpy array? Could you add something like `a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])` so we can easily see what you mean?

Comment: The documentation for `add.at` indicates that `a += 1` does a certain amount of buffering  - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html.  Details are buried in `numpy` code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
numpy.subtract(1, a, out=a)
```

Using the `subtract` ufunc directly gives you more control than the `-` operator. Here, we use the `out` parameter to place the results of the subtraction back into `a`.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: `a` is a NumPy array. We're already using NumPy. The cost of importing NumPy is a sunk cost, not an additional cost to pay for using this code.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in place like so:

```
a *= -1
a += 1
```